Origin of a special Sinhala letterform
In Sinhala, the usual form of the short U diacritic is that of a hook on the bottom of a letter:
a) ක + ‌ු -> කු, කූ
b) ම + ‌ු -> මු, මූ
This takes an exceptional form for the letter R, like this, which I think can be explained with the diacritic in b) being "rotated":
c) ර + ‌ු -> රු, රූ
This would be by analogy with the I diacritic rotating:
ර +  ි -> රි
However there is a much stranger exception for the character for historical retroflex L:
d) ළ + ‌ු -> ළු, ළූ.
How did this come about? Can you recommend sources that talk about this?

Devanāgarī also has special forms for ru, rū, by the way.
